# vscode, addMissingImports после замены текста по проекту

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Проблема такая, в настройках vscode стоит настройка

```
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,
        "source.organizeImports": true,
        "source.addMissingImports": true
      }
```

Если сохраняю какой то конкретный файл, то `addMissingImports` работает, но когда я по `ctrl+shift+h` делаю замену в проекте, то поведение странное, для нескольких файлов импорт все таки добавляется, но для большинства из списка уже нет. Файлов несколько десятков, добавляется в 2-3. Как сделать чтобы работало для всех? Пишу на javascript, checkJs включен.

Comment: Выяснилось, что действия на сохранение производятся только над файлами отрытыми в редакторе

Comment: Если найдете решение, будет круто!) Очень не хватает, чтобы все файлы проекта анализировались.